# Vim: set history=500 in .vimrc not taking effect

Tags: vim

On an Ubuntu 12 system with Vim 7.3, a strange thing is happening. I have `:set history=500` in my `~/.vimrc` file. I have numerous settings in that file which all work. The history feature works: `~/.viminfo` has good permissions, and things are being retained in it: command and search histories, position of the cursor in files, contents of registers and so on. However, after launching Vim, if I do `:set all`, I see `history=20` in spite of the setting in `~/.vimrc`.

If I interactively do `:set history=500`, then it sticks.

I did a recursive search through all Vim-related files in the system, looking for a rogue `set history` command, but found nothing.

Answer (score 3):

While posting my question, I continued to probe into this and discovered the solution just before submitting it. This could be valuable to future visitors.

The answer is that `:set history` must be placed after `:set nocompatible` in your `.vimrc` file.  This is in spite of the fact that some other settings which are Vim extensions are accepted before that option, such as `:set backupdir`.

The issue is not that `:set history` is *rejected* in compatibility mode.

Rather, `:set nocompatible` has the *side effect* of resetting the history to the default 20: it is the "rogue command" I was looking for.

You can try this:

```
:set nocompatible
:set history=500
:set nocompatible
```

The `:set history=500` command takes effect, but the second `:set nocompatible` changes `history` to 20!

#### Post-Mortem Addendum:

**Note: while it is true today that processing a `.vimrc` file implies `nocompatible`, as a comment points out, that has not historically been the case.**

You can see in the [Vim 3.0 sources](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/unix/vim-3.0.tar.gz) which fairly closely match the version that **I started using in 1994,** that the `dosource` function in `cmdline.c` doesn't take any flags arguments and doesn't do anything special when a `.vimrc` is processed. You must explicitly set `:nocompatible` in `.vimrc`.

In newer sources, the function `do_source` knows, via a flag, that it's processing a `.vimrc` file and if the file exists, it calls a function called `vimrc_found` in `options.c` which resets the compatibility flag.

Vim introduced this behavior without producing any helpful diagnostic for users who continued to have a now useless and potentially harmful `:set nocompatible` in their `.vimrc` files, carrying that ["onion in the varnish"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?OnionInTheVarnish) from one system to the next.

Another thing to note is that **resetting** the compatibility option had no additional side effects in Vim 3. Only **setting** the option (telling Vim to be compatible). You can see this in the `param.c` source file in the `doset` function. There is a check that if the option that has just been tweaked is the compatibility option, and that option is now Boolean true, then tweak a myriad other settings in order to be more like Vi. There is no such behavior as setting the history to 20 when the option is turned off.

In other words, since `:set nocompatible` once had no side effects other than clearing `compatible`, **it didn't matter that it was preceded by other settings**.   The Vim maintainers added side effects to `:set nocompatible` without caring that old users might still have this command in their `.vimrc` files, and not at the top.

*TL; DR; I'm not an idiot.*

Comment: Everything should be placed after nocompatible. nocompatible changes a lot of settings and its not worth the hassle to figure out which ones are changed. You don't even need to set it since having a vimrc set it implicitly.

Comment: @FDinoff In that case, its only effect in `~/.vimrc` should be ... the issuance of a warning diagnostic.

Comment: The first line in everyone's `~/.vimrc` should be `set nocompatible`. However, it's best to wrap it in a conditional, only set it if the mode was previously compatible, `if &compatible` then set it.

Comment: @FDinoff See edit. When I started using Vim `:set nocompatible` had no side effects beyond clearing the parameter to zero, and loading `.vimrc` didn't affect the compatibility option.

Comment: @Corey That is incorrect.  Back when it was *required*, it didn't matter whether it was the first line or not. Today, it is not required, and may interfere with settings from other `.vimrc` files.  For instance, if you set `history` in a master Vimrc file in `/etc/`, then `:set nocompatible` in a local `.vimrc` will clobber it.

Comment: @Corey And your comment underscores the point that this is obscure stuff that changed, and is contrary to the intuitions of long time users.

Comment: @Kaz Interesting. I haven't been using vim that long. I think I started around vim 7.3... I imagine this was a side effect of there being more options which didn't make sense in compatible mode. The vim maintainers try not to break stuff. But I don't know when they started doing that. They did think about it eventually as theres a "CAREFUL: Setting or  resetting this option can have a lot of unexpected effects" in the help page but who knows how many people complained. (I also wonder how many people read the help pages sometimes)